# How should I integrate my ERC-20 Smart Contract into the existing cryptocurrency ecosystem?

Tags: erc-20, tokens

I've created my own cryptocurrency based on the ERC-20 Smart Contract on the Ethereum blockchain. I want my currency to have the same functionality as Tether USDT, for example. To be more specific:

1. I'd like popular crypto wallets like Exodus to support my cryptocurrency.
2. I want people interested in my cryptocurrency to be able to buy or sell my tokens via popular crypto exchanges like Binance.

What steps should I take to achieve these goals? What do I need to do to make my cryptocurrency a fully functional digital currency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It being an `ERC-20` token and adhering to the [standard](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/) is enough for the token to be supported by Exodus, Metamask or any other wallet that supports the EVM compatible chain your token is on.

You will likely have to add the token address manually:

- https://www.exodus.com/support/article/1838-custom-tokens
- https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360015489031-How-to-display-tokens-in-MetaMask

Wallets auto adding some token addresses via API is a relatively new feature and you would have to research inclusion in to those lists, just as you would inclusion by any centralised exchange.

The token functions and ERC20 standard, have little to do with if Binance will be willing to list it. That is more political than technical.

Though you could sell it on any decentralised exchange that supports ERC20 tokens, by adding liquidity just as you can with tether.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer!

Comment: Much love and good luck on your journey.